# Simple jQuery vertical text scroller

Tags: jquery, text, scroll

I'm am looking for a simple jQuery script that will scroll text within a div vertically while pauses for a few seconds at a time - can anyone recommend any good clean jQuery plugins that you have used that can do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This post might be able to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531508/simple-jquery-vertical-text-scroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript's [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) and jQuery's [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to accomplish this.

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drewP/fWhxX/2/) of what I have come up with. Hope this helps.